# 漏拆 - Meaning & usage?

Tags: translation, grammar, vocabulary

I tried several sources & can't find a translation that seems correct.

An example sentence & my attempt at translation:

嘴里漏拆了一根线怎么办？

mouth inside left behind remove a strip of thread what to do?

"There's a thread (of stitches?) left behind (not removed) in my mouth, what should I do?"

漏 means "missed" or "left behind"
拆 means "to dismantle" or "take down"

So 漏 is modifying the verb 拆 to make it mean "not dismantled or taken down", sort of.

Is my understanding correct? Can 漏 modify other verbs in this way?

Thanks in advance for any teaching!

Comment: When there's a wound in mouth, the doctor would suture it. And when the wound recovers, the stitches should be removed. So, "嘴里漏拆了一根线" means the omission of a careless doctor who hasn't removed all stitches in the mouth ...

Answer (score 7):

First of all, "There's stitches left behind (not removed) in my mouth, what should I do?" is a good translation.

Yes,漏 can modify other verbs. It means someone forgot to do something or some action has been missed.

Example:

A:"How you feel about the question 31 in the exam?"

B:"OMG, I didn't notice there was a question 31!"

A:"刚才考试第31题做的如何？"

B:"天啊！ 我漏做了!"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually a word. When you study Chinese, you shouldn't regard any pair of characters as a meaningful word. If you also study 文言文，you will find that people in ancient times often used only one character as a verb or a noun. That's why there are so many characters no longer used today: people use two-character words to express the meanings that were originally represented by a single character.

Nowadays, there are still many occasions in Chinese that people use only one character as one word. So you have to learn how to partition a sentence into several meaningful blocks.